# In Mandarin Chinese, what is the correct pronunciation for three or more third tones in a row?

Tags: mandarin, tones, sandhi

只有我想了解你
zhíyǒu wǒ xiǎng liáojiě nǐ
OR 
Zhíyǒu wó xiǎng liáojiě nǐ

我很好
wǒ hén hǎo
OR
wó hén hǎo

我也很好
wó yě hén hǎo
OR 
wó yé hén hǎo
OR 
wǒ yé hén hǎo

我也很想你
wǒ yé hěn xiáng nǐ
OR 
wǒ yé hén xiǎng nǐ
OR
wó yé hěn xiáng nǐ

我很想买水果
wó yě hén xiǎng mǎi shuíguǒ
OR
wó yé hén xiáng mǎi shuíguǒ
OR 
Wǒ hén xiáng mǎi shuíguǒ

我也很想买水果
wó yě hén xiǎng mái shuí guǒ
OR
wó yě hén xiǎng mǎi shuí guǒ

等你好久
déng ní háo jiǔ
OR
děng ní háo jiǔ
OR 
déng nǐ háo jiǔ

九九九九
jiújiǔjiújiǔ

Comment: isn't such rules taught in textbook?

Comment: I think the answer can be found in [Generalize consecutive third tones change rule](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21395/generalize-consecutive-third-tones-change-rule) and [How does tone sandhi apply in people's names?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/how-does-tone-sandhi-apply-in-peoples-names).  By the way, you know you can edit questions [and this is preferred], rather than delete and repost?

Comment: Worth adding is that how much sandhi occurs is also due to rate of speech, so someone speaking faster will change more low tones to rising tones.

Answer (score 1):

只有我想了解你  Zhíyóu wó xiǎng liáojié nǐ

我很好 wǒ hén hǎo

我也很好 wó yě hén hǎo

我也很想你 wó yě hén xiáng nǐ

我很想买水果 wǒ hén xiáng mǎi shuíguǒ

我也很想买水果 wó yě hén xiáng mǎi shuí guǒ

等你好久 déng nǐ háo jiǔ

九九九九 jiújiújiújiǔ